# Creating a calculator that tells you who hosts every 6 years automatically using Switch in C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

- I am having trouble with the problem below.
- I can get the correct answers, but if I enter any years over 3 years for each person, the name {0} will be blank.

  - I am trying to calculate for any year, not just stop calculating who hosts it after 3 years after they first started hosting. I know it has something to do with my if (year modulus ? == ?).
- Please help.

---

Calculate who hosts the grammy awards. Each person has to do it every 3 years. Tupac hosted the first grammy in year 1970, meaning he would host year 1973, 1976, 1979…

You need to calculate the next years using these people. They started:

- Tupac = 1970
- Usher = 1971
- Mario = 1972

Answers:

- Enter the year: 1973 ... "Hello tupac, you are the host of year 1973”
- Enter the year: 1974 ... "Hello usher, you are the host of year 1974”
- Enter the year: 1978 ... "Hello mario, you are the host of year 1978”

---

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int year = 0;
        string name = "";

        Console.Write("Enter the year: ");
        year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (year % 1970 == 3)
        {
            name = "Tupac";
        }
        if (year % 1971 == 3)
        {
            name = "Usher";
        }
        if (year % 1972 == 3)
        {
            name = "Mario";
        }

        switch (year)
        {
            default:
                Console.Write("Hello {0}, you are the host of year {1}", name, year);
                break;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You may want to double-check syntax of "operator %" in any C-like language... I'm not exactly sure what you think `a % b == c` means but overall looks like just typo. (Why sample provided in the post is using `switch` is very unclear - you really don't need to show that part for [MCVE])

Comment: You're not going to find a whole lot of people interested in doing your homework for you but I'm willing to at least point you in the right direction. If you're required to use a `switch`, your `if` statements are unnecessary (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch). You're on the right track by using the `%` operator but your usage is incorrect (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-).

Comment: Replace your `if`s with a `switch`. Bias the entered year by the starting year (`year-1970`). Use the `%` to figure out which multiple you are at. Excel/a calculator is useful to figure out what your expression is doing given a series of years. Understand `%`.

Answer (score 0):

I've introduced `GrammyHost` class and a list of grammy hosts:

```cs
class GrammyHost
{
    public GrammyHost(string name, int year)
    {
        Name = name;
        Year = year;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public int Year { get; }

    public bool ShouldHostGrammyThisYear(int thisYear)
    {
        if (thisYear < Year)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return ((thisYear - Year) % 3) == 0;
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the year: ");

        // Let's create a list of possible hosts
        var grammyHosts = new List<GrammyHost>
        {
            new GrammyHost("Tupac", 1970),
            new GrammyHost("Usher", 1971),
            new GrammyHost("Mario", 1972)
        };

        var thisYear = 0;
        thisYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // Search for this year host
        var thisYearHost = grammyHosts
            .FirstOrDefault(host => host.ShouldHostGrammyThisYear(thisYear));

        // If it's null then there is no host this year...
        if (thisYearHost is null)
        {
            Console.Write("No host this year...");
        }
        else // Otherwise print the host
        {
            Console.Write("Hello {0}, you are the host of year {1}", thisYearHost.Name, thisYear);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Your conditions were incorrect. Look at the `ShouldHostGrammyThisYear` method in `GrammyHost` class:

```cs
if (thisYear < Year)
{
    return false;
}

return ((thisYear - Year) % 3) == 0;
```

First we check if this year is valid in context of the current person. The host cannot travel back in time so if `thisYear` is before `GrammyHost.Year` we return false without further checks.

Then if you look at the return statement we calculate the difference to know how many years have passed sinced `GrammyHost.Year` to `thisYear` and check if the difference is divisible by 3. In other words the difference tells us how many years have passed since the host hosted the grammy first time and if that difference is divisible by 3 then it means the host should host the grammy this year.

e.g. let's say `thisYear` is 1973 and `GrammyHost.Year` is 1970 (Tupac). The difference is `1973 - 1970 = 3`. We check if it is divisible by 3 using `%` operator to calculate the remainder and then comparing it (remainder) to zero. In a case of `Tupac` the difference is 3 and it is indeed divisible by 3, so 3 % 3 will result in 0.

If the remainder is not equal to zero then it means that difference was not divisible by 3 therefore the host should not host the grammy this year.

Also I think there is no need for a switch-case.